# Can eventhubs and service bus be added to a resource group in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am working on building a multitenant application in Azure and though resources groups would be a good way to separate the tenants but could not find a way to add eventhub or service bus queues to a resource group.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, No. From what I understand there's a concept of a resource provider for each resource type and a resource type must have a resource provider in order to be added to resource group (rather support Azure Resource Manager) and as of today there's no resource provider for Service Bus.

Comment: Looks like it's on the way: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/8625268-expose-service-bus-and-event-hub-through-resource